# Function/meaning of ~ . for train function in caret R package

Tags: r, r-caret

```
train(Class ~ ., data = training, 
                 method = "gbm", 
                 trControl = fitControl,
                 ## This last option is actually one
                 ## for gbm() that passes through
                 verbose = FALSE)
```

I know that Class is predictor but what i do not understand is meaning/need of **~ .**

Any help or pointers towards help will  be highly appreciated.

PS. I am new to R

Comment: It's a formula, means that Class is predicted using all other variables in data.

Comment: @r.user.05apr , Is there any documentation on how to use/create this formula/filter? I mean how can i customize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means anything else except  `medv`(in this example) like the normal usage in a formula. Basically you're predicting against all predictors in the dataset. Take for instance this:

```
library(caret)
library(mlbench)
data(BostonHousing)
lmFit <- train(medv ~ . + rm:lstat,
               data = BostonHousing,
               method = "lm")
```

To see the terms call `lmFit$terms`. Of significance is this:

```
medv ~ crim + zn + indus + chas + nox + rm + age + dis + rad + 
    tax + ptratio + b + lstat + rm:lstat
```

You can exclude like so:

```
lmFit <- train(medv ~.-zn -so on -so on  + rm:lstat,
               data = BostonHousing,
               method = "lm")
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I exclude ( crim,zn,indus) these columns from the same example?

Comment: Thanks for edit for So for removing column we need "-"coulmnName1 "-"coulmnName2  separated  by space. One more question what is purpose of "+ rm:lstat" in this.

Comment: The +rm:lstat is showing an interaction between rm and lstat. You don't need the quotes. Just -column 1 -column 2 etc

Comment: Can you please share resources to learn more about it ? Like link to doc or book ?

Comment: Normally read up on several different articles as I work. However, Brett Lantz's book on Machine Learning with R might be a good place to start(more theoretical). Alternatively you could go through the caret vignette. Link to vignette https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/vignettes/caret.html